# Rails console doesn't work (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

RuntimeError with the rails console,  rails server works as expected.

I'm using a Mac OSX SL

ruby version `ruby 2.2.3p136 (2015-06-17 revision 50924) [i386-darwin10.0]`

rails version `Rails 4.2.2`

If I use `bundle console` with  `require_relative 'config/environment.rb'` it normally works

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:351:in `initialize!': Application has been already initialized. (RuntimeError)
from /users/mario/Sites/store4/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /users/mario/Sites/store4/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and move to your project directory and run this.

```
rails console
```

or if you are already in your project run the same command from there.

```
iMac-di-Mario:store4 mario$ pwd /Users/mario/Sites/store4 $ rails console
```

Comment: I'm already in the project directory    `iMac-di-Mario:store4 mario$ pwd
/Users/mario/Sites/store4`

Comment: Then please run the above command. What is bundle console?. Please run rails console not bundle console.

Comment: Can you please paste the error trace. In general rails console is used to open the console.